# How to get django form errors as text instead of html?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a toast for displaying errors.

```
$.toast({
    text: '{{ form.non_field_errors }}'
})
```

But it is returning a html format. so i am getting an error.
[image]

But i would like to get text only from `{{ form.non_field_errors }}`. How do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.as_text()` method, on the `non_field_errors`:

```
$.toast({
    text: '{{ form.non_field_errors.as_text }}'
})
```

Note however that in order to make this more safe, you better JSON-ify this, and furthermore mark the output as safe.

You thus better do some processing in the view:

```
from json import dumps as jdumps

def some_view(request):
    some_form = ModelForm(request.POST)
    errors = jdumps(some_form.non_field_errors().as_text())
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'errors': errors})
```

and in the template render this as:

```
$.toast({
    text: {{ errors|safe }}
})
```